# Chef trying to load its own cookbook within the process

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm in the process of creating a cookbook for Magento with the aid of Kitchen.CI

I'm using Librarian-Chef for dependency management, and since I installed it, I'm getting the following error when I try to converge:

```
ERROR: Cookbook magentochef not found. If you're loading magentochef from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

Here's the thing, magentochef is the name of the cookbook I'm creating, so I have no idea why it's trying to load it as a dependency. In effect, it's trying to load itself as a dependency to itself, which is strange indeed.

I am new to Chef and Kitchen.CI so it's possible that I'm misunderstanding something, but it does seem very odd that this is happening. The error occurred only after I installed `librarian-chef` and tried to run `kitchen converge`

Here's my metadata.rb

```
name "magentochef"
version "0.0.1"
```

Here's my .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
  - name: ubuntu-14.04

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[magentochef::default]
    attributes:
```

And lastly, my Cheffile

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#^syntax detection

site 'https://supermarket.getchef.com/api/v1'

cookbook 'composer', '~> 1.0.5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `cookbook 'magentochef', path: '.'` to your Cheffile. Berkshelf is more common for this and includes a helper (`metadata`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll test in the morning and let you know how it goes!